# Hiding/showing divs in mobile view using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a page where I have to panes (left/right). Left pane will show the list of items and right pane will show the detail of selected item from left pane.  However, when same page being displayed in Mobile it should show only List of item first.  When selected any item in the list, than list pane should be hidden and detail pane should be showing.  Detail pane will have a back button, which show the Left(list pane) and hide the detail pane.

**Question:  How can I achieve this scenario in twitter bootstrap?**

Comment: Please show us an example of what you've tried and done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you can hide the panel right panel initially by using `.hidden-md hidden-lg`, but after that you would need to enable things and hide them again with JS .toggle() or just literally `.removeClass("...")` and `.addClass("...")`

Comment: I thought, there may be some way of handling automatically in bootstrap.  I was bit lazy to write javascript to handle this.  May be bootstrap have some in-built javascript which it loads when it is open in mobile mode.

Comment: Maybe. To be honest I would recommend that instead of hiding and showing things you just put the right panel underneath the left panel and on click it jumps down. This would allow for a better user experience. Also what would happen if the users after misclicked the first time and the left panel disappeared?

Comment: Back button on detail pane should do reverse.